# UVA 100: "The 3n + 1 problem"

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, c++11, dynamic-programming, collatz-sequence

I’ve solved UVA Problem 100: [The 3n + 1 problem](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36) . In short, the task was to write a program that calculates a maximum of Collatz sequence lengths for any given range of starting values.

My program:

```
#ifdef ONLINE_JUDGE
  #define NODEBUG
#endif

#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

using seqlen = unsigned short;
using seqval = unsigned long;

constexpr seqval inputMax = 999999;
constexpr seqval inputMin = 1;

seqlen getLength(seqval n)
{
  assert(n%2 == 0 || n <= (UINT32_MAX-1)/3);

  static unordered_map<seqval,seqlen> cache {{1,1}};

  if(cache.count(n)) return cache[n];
  return cache[n] = getLength(n%2==0 ? n/2 : 3*n+1) + 1;
}

seqlen getRangeMax(seqval i, seqval j)
{
  assert(i <= j);
  assert(i >= inputMin && j <= inputMax+1);

  using cache_t = vector<unordered_map<seqval,seqlen>>;
  static cache_t cache;

  if(i == j) return 0;

  auto exponent = static_cast<cache_t::size_type>(floor(log2(j-i)));
  auto interval = static_cast<seqval>(pow(2,exponent));

  seqval lb, ub;
  while((lb = (ub = interval * (j/interval)) - interval) < i)
    interval = static_cast<seqval>(pow(2,--exponent));

  if(exponent == 0) return getLength(lb);

  cache.resize(max(cache.size(), exponent));
  return max(
    max(getRangeMax(i, lb), getRangeMax(ub, j)),
    cache[exponent-1].count(lb) ?
      cache[exponent-1][lb] :
      cache[exponent-1][lb] =
        max(getRangeMax(lb, lb+interval/2), getRangeMax(lb+interval/2, ub)));  
}

struct testCase
{
  seqval i=0, j=0;

  friend istream &operator >> (istream &is, testCase &tc)
  {
    if((is>>ws).eof()) {return is;}
    string inpstr; getline(is, inpstr); if(!is.good()) return is;
    stringstream inp(inpstr+'\n'); inp >> tc.i >> tc.j;
    if(!inp.good()) {is.setstate(inp.rdstate() | 
      ((inp.rdstate()&ios_base::eofbit) != 0 ?
      ios_base::failbit : static_cast<ios_base::iostate>(0))
    ); return is;}
    if(tc.i < inputMin || tc.j < inputMin || tc.i > inputMax || tc.j > inputMax)
      {is.setstate(ios_base::failbit); return is;}
    if(!(inp>>ws).eof()) {is.setstate(ios_base::failbit); return is;}
    return is;
  }

  bool noInput() {return i==0 || j==0;}
};

int main()
{
  #ifdef NODEBUG
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
  #endif

  cin.exceptions(ios_base::failbit | ios_base::badbit);
  cout.exceptions(ios_base::eofbit | ios_base::failbit | ios_base::badbit);
  testCase tc; while(!(cin >> tc).eof())
    cout << tc.i << ' ' << tc.j << ' ' <<
      getRangeMax(min(tc.i,tc.j), max(tc.i,tc.j)+1) << '\n';
  if(tc.noInput()) cout << '\n';

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Notes:

- People tell me my code tends to be ugly and unreadable; I tried to make this one reasonably readable, and I’d especially like to hear comments on this matter.
- My goals I tried to meet as a self-imposed challenge:

  - I tried to achieve sound time complexity even despite the judge’s lax requirements do not force me to do so.
  - I also tried to write error safe code, in particular I wanted to make the program fail on input that is invalid as per the problem specification.

    - Problem #1: This means I needed to distinguish the cases of lack of further input and the presence of an invalid input line. To meet this I broke conventions set up by the Standard Library by making `operator>>(istream&,testCase&)` only set `eofbit` on lack of input but ***not*** `failbit`. I guess this is bad, but as of now I have no better idea.
    - Problem #2: I still cannot prevent UB in case of a stack overflow and I don’t think it is even possible in general. Maybe I should’ve refrained from using recursion?
  - I tried to refrain from making use of any unnecessary implementation-specific guarantees, and instead make the program have to produce correct results as per the C++ Standard. As of now I can’t see where could I fail in here, but I’ve already [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915434/is-it-guaranteed-that-size-t-vectorsize-type-etc-typedefs-wont-bind-to-a-ch) that there are unobvious issues on this matter.
- As of now, the [problem specification](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36) gives incorrect input boundaries, claiming that all numbers will be less than 10,000. The correct bound seems to be 1,000,000 instead, which is present in the [archived version of the problem specification](http://web.archive.org/web/20161225044321/https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36).

Comment: Also compilers don't care about whitespace, but people trying to decipher your code do.  All those inline statements make it much harder to see what your code is doing.

Comment: @tinstaafl You may be right… But I was only trying to make the code more concise. For example, this line: `while((lb = (ub = interval * (j/interval)) - interval) < i)` actually saves me from having to define a whole function. Err, the code is already 100 lines long…

Answer (score 5):

> People tell me my code tends to be ugly and unreadable; I tried to make this one reasonably readable, and I’d especially like to hear comments on this matter.

I'll do my best to keep this kind. People are right, and I'd like to explain why. In the comments, tinstaafl wrote:

> All those inline statements make it much harder to see what your code is doing.

To which you reply:

> But I was only trying to make the code more concise.

You didn't. Concise code is not code that has as few lines as possible. It is code which expresses exactly what it needs to without any extraneous statements. You haven't reduced the number of statements, just the number of lines. The number of lines of code is relatively unimportant, so long as the code is organized well, easy to understand, and performs well.

For example, you have this:

```
return max(
    max(getRangeMax(i, lb), getRangeMax(ub, j)),
    cache[exponent-1].count(lb) ?
       cache[exponent-1][lb] :
       cache[exponent-1][lb] =
        max(getRangeMax(lb, lb+interval/2), getRangeMax(lb+interval/2, ub)));
```

This is not concise. And it's worse than not being concise. It has a very unexpected assignment in the middle of it which will cause it to be misunderstood by nearly every person besides you who tries to read it. It's a bunch of conditionals, assignments, calculations, and branches all crammed into a function call which is also a return statement. The compiler will generate the same results if you write it as:

```
seqlen result;
seqlen max1 = max(getRangeMax(i, lb), getRangeMax(ub, j));

if (cache[exponent - 1].count[lb] != 0) 
{
    result = max(max1, cache [ exponent - 1 ][ lb ];
}
else
{
    seqlen max2 = max(getRangeMax(lb, lb+interval/2), getRangeMax(lb+interval/2, ub));
    result = max(max1, max2);
    cache [ exponent - 1 ][ lb ] = max2;
}

return result;
```

Now other people can also read it at a glance and understand what it does without having to first untangle a bunch of other stuff. (Although you should use more descriptive variable names than I've used. I don't know this particular mathematical construct well enough to name things properly.)

## Debugging

Your stream operator is particularly egregious. If there's an error in it, how will you debug it? Try stepping through it in a debugger. When you get to, say, this line:

```
string inpstr; getline(is, inpstr); if(!is.good()) return is;
```

and find an error in it, how do you know which of those 3 statements contains the error? You can't step over one to the other because it's all one line. That doesn't help anyone.

Are you sure this statement is correct?

```
if(!inp.good()) {is.setstate(inp.rdstate() | 
  ((inp.rdstate()&ios_base::eofbit) != 0 ?
  ios_base::failbit : static_cast<ios_base::iostate>(0))
); return is;}
```

Is the operator precedence correct? Does logical or come before not equal? I don't remember and if I have to edit that line in the future, I'm likely to screw it up because it's all crammed together and uses minimal parentheses.

Also, you seem concerned about having too many lines, but I count 5... no wait... 6 `return is;` statements. The flow control of that function is terrible.

One way you could improve it is by having an error variable that you check for whether you should continue or not. For example, this would be one common way to write it:

```
friend istream &operator >> (istream &is, testCase &tc)
{
    bool error = false;
    if((is>>ws).eof()) {
        error = true;
    }

    if (!error) {
        string inpstr; 
        getline(is, inpstr); 
        if (!is.good()) {
            error = true;
        }
    }

    if (!error) {
        stringstream inp(inpstr+'\n'); 
        inp >> tc.i >> tc.j;

        if(!inp.good()) {
            is.setstate(inp.rdstate() | 
                ((inp.rdstate()&ios_base::eofbit) != 0 ?
                ios_base::failbit : static_cast<ios_base::iostate>(0))); 
            error = true;
        }
    }

    if (!error) {
        if(tc.i < inputMin || tc.j < inputMin || tc.i > inputMax || tc.j > inputMax) {
            is.setstate(ios_base::failbit); 
            error = true;
        }
    }

    if (!error) {
        if (!(inp>>ws).eof()) {
            is.setstate(ios_base::failbit); 
            error = true;
        }
    }

    return is;
}
```

The reason this is better than returning on error is because it's easy to see at a glance the flow of control. If you needed to allocate a resource at the beginning of the function and release it on return, you now only have a single place you need to do it. (Granted C++ has some good tools for making that much easier, but it can still come up in real-world use.) With your version, I can't tell quickly if there are non-error returns or if all returns but the last are for error cases.

If you want to write concise code learn how to express your ideas with fewer statements rather than fewer lines. And also remember that there's a difference between concise and densely packed. It can be easy to write a very short statement or set of statements which do many things, but if it's too subtle, people who have to maintain it (which is you in a few months time) won't be able to see that subtlety when time is critical.

Comment: `I don't know this particular mathematical construct well enough` Ugh, so I guess I must’ve screwed things up really badly. These are simple partial sums, or at least that is how I call this, I dunno how is this “officialy” called. Anyway, the concept is really simple: You precompute sums (or maximums) of elements `1-2, 3-4`, etc, and then of elements `1-4, 5-8`, and then `1-8, 9-16`, etc, etc. So that when you, for example, have to get a maximum of elements `1-10`, you have the result of elts `4-7` given, and you still only have to recursively consider elts `1-3` and `8-10`.

Comment: Thus, you can get these sums in logarithmic time rather than linear. I only adjusted this concept slightly to the fact that I’d like to cache things rather than precompute them.

Comment: `Also, you seem concerned about having too many lines, but I count 5... no wait... 6 return is; statements.` So, I presume, it is wrong to write code like this: `if(errorCondition) {setErrorFlag; return;}` If returning immediately on error is wrong, then what should I do instead? How to fix the control flow without executing subsequent statements that are now meaningless because an error has occured?

Comment: Regarding me not knowing this function - I don't think it's due to your code, I just haven't run into it before. I was more focused on the things you asked about. Regarding early returns - it's a style choice that affects readability. Personally, I find that having one or two at the very start of the function for things like invalid, or degenerate inputs is fine. But when there are several at different places in a function, it can become difficult to figure out whether a given input will cause an early return or not, so it's hard to reason about.

Comment: I am sorry, but in that case I still dunno how to write this operator properly. Its **only** purpose is to check correctness of the input. Thus, essentially, it is a series of tests – should input fail any of these tests, return with error. Finally, if no error was spotted, return with success. Not sure how can I maintain this purpose of this operator while refraining from most early `return`s. For example, I can only check if the integers are not too small or too large after I read them, so I can’t do this `at the very start of the function`.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how you can check for errors without having multiple return statements.

Comment: Thank you. Still, I’m kinda unsure how is this better than returning on error…

Comment: I've added a paragraph explaining my reasoning below the code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

> People tell me my code tends to be ugly and unreadable; I tried to make this one reasonably readable, and I’d especially like to hear comments on this matter.

I'll have to agree with the other "people" on this one: Even though you said that you tried to make it more readable, it is still a huge mess of unreadable code. It seems that you think that the less line your code has, the better. That's not the case though. It's true that less lines of code is better, but that doesn't mean you need to cram multiple statements on one line just to reduces the total count of lines:

```
if((is>>ws).eof()) {return is;}
string inpstr; getline(is, inpstr); if(!is.good()) return is;
stringstream inp(inpstr+'\n'); inp >> tc.i >> tc.j;
if(!inp.good()) {is.setstate(inp.rdstate() | 
  ((inp.rdstate()&ios_base::eofbit) != 0 ?
  ios_base::failbit : static_cast<ios_base::iostate>(0))
); return is;}
if(tc.i < inputMin || tc.j < inputMin || tc.i > inputMax || tc.j > inputMax)
  {is.setstate(ios_base::failbit); return is;}
if(!(inp>>ws).eof()) {is.setstate(ios_base::failbit); return is;}
return is;
```

That part is especially unreadable, don't you think? Well, let's see if we can make your code readable :)

---

#### Don't use `using namespace std;`

It is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), so please refrain from using it.

#### You don't need to return anything on success from `main`

You don't need to `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`, as the compiler will implicitly use it if you don't specify it. But that's pretty opinion based.

#### Use better naming

You have some `i` and `j` outside of loops. Those are very bad variable names, they don't tell what `i` and `j` do. I also find that `getLength` isn't an ideal name considering that getting the length of an integer doesn't make any sense.

#### Use proper indentation and don't stick lines together

As said before, you seem to like putting multiple statements in one line:

```
string inpstr; getline(is, inpstr); if(!is.good()) return is;
```

Those lines are *really* unreadable and hard to debug. Same thing goes for lines without indentation and/or whitespace:

```
if(!(inp>>ws).eof()) {is.setstate(ios_base::failbit); return is;}
```

Please use your <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> keys :)

#### `std::pow` has poor performance

`std::pow` is (very) slow to calculate powers, that's because it can also calculate powers of floating point numbers, and thus can't use the traditional approach. It would be better (and faster!) if you made your own exponentiation function:

```
constexpr auto pow(unsigned long long base, unsigned long long exp) noexcept {
    auto result = 1ull;
    for (auto i = 0ull; i < exp; ++i)
        result *= base;
    return result;
}
```

#### Why use macros?

I don't see any reason to use macros, especially since you cannot debug your code easily. Also, for debugging purposes, it is not really important that `stdio` is synced, as you're not even using `stdio`. Same for tying `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

#### `testCase` is weird and complicated

Your `testCase` struct is very complicated and long and weird. I don't know why you don't use:

```
seqval num1 = 0;
seqval num2 = 0;
while(std::cin >> num1 >> num2)
  std::cout << num1 << ' ' << num2 << ' ' << getRangeMax(std::min(num1, num2), std::max(num1, num2)+1) << '\n';
```

This will always get input from `stdin` until EOF is reached. Because online judges will pass input from a file (I can't imagine them doing something else - maybe they are, but that's the easy solution), it will behave as expected.

If you want to stop the input and see the output, just input anything that is not a number (except for a space or a newline of course).

<sub>If you tie `std::cout` and `std::cin` again, you'll see the output immediately, instead of at the end.</sub>

#### Your algorithm is unclear to me

The algorithm that you are using is very unclear from just looking at the code IMO, so I can't give you any tips on this one, just give you how I would solve the problem. This is the best examples where comments would really help out to understand the algorithm you are using.

The combination of striving to minimize code lines, bad naming, no comments is the reason why it is hard for me to understand it.

Here's how I would do it:

```
seqlen calculate_collatz(seqval number) noexcept {
    seqlen length = 1;
    while (number != 1) {
        if (number % 2 == 0)
            number /= 2;
        else
            number = 3 * number + 1;

        ++length;
    }

    return length;
}

seqlen max_collatz(seqval lower, seqval upper) noexcept {
    seqlen largest_sequence = 0;
    for (auto i = lower; i < upper + 1; ++i) {
        auto curr_sequence = calculate_collatz(i);
        if (curr_sequence > largest_sequence)
            largest_sequence = curr_sequence;
    }

    return largest_sequence;
}
```

You might notice that I haven't used any cache. That's because even without a cache, my way is 0.6s faster than yours (0.2s vs. 0.8s)! <sub>Both were compiled using `-O3` with `gcc 6.3.1` on a i7-6700HQ.</sub>

With a cache, I would say that using a cache will make the algorithm even faster. Also, you might want to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38885614/longest-collatz-or-hailstone-sequence-optimization-python-2-7), as it explains what you can do to optimize the algorithm even further. For example, only caching odd numbers.

Comment: I must say Your answer gave a few points I have difficulty with. `Don't use using namespace std;`– in large programs, sure. But in such a program like this – I can’t see any particular benefit of refraining from `using namespace std;`… But I can still see all that clutter I’m avoiding. `You don't need to return anything on success from main` Sure. But, well, my idea was to make the program fail on any error (like invalid input) due to an exception being thrown. So, `return EXIT_SUCCESS` kinda means here that the program reaaalllyy finished successfully :)

Comment: `Use better naming` The only reason I was using variable names `i` and `j` is that I was solving Problem 100 from UVA, and these exact names appear in the [problem specification](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36). So, with the use of these names I wanted to make it obvious that these variables bind to the ones from the problem specification.

Comment: `std::pow has poor performance` Wow, here I learn something new. Thanks. Well, I still have to performance test this, but… this is an unobvious pitfall… Especially evil since stdlib [seems to provide](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) overloads for integer exponents! Ah wait, it doesn’t, these are cast to double… rrrgh. My thinking was that authors of stdlib should make everything far better optimized than I ever could, so whenever possible I should use language construct rather than my own functions.

Comment: `Why use macros?` From [my performance tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166263/how-to-get-iostream-to-perform-better/35340653#35340653) untying `cin` from `cout` may speed things up significantly, but it makes debugging a little harder since I can’t see output when it is printed out. So, I thought I’d disable this for the debug version. Bad idea? `testCase is weird and complicated` The only purpose of this structure and `operator>>` is to check input correctness. Onlinejudge doesn’t care about this, but I noted I wanted to do this as a self-imposed challenge.

Comment: @gaazkam Well, fair enough, although it is a bit overkill. I guess it makes debugging a little harder, but it's your call :)

Comment: `Your algorithm is unclear to me` Ugh. Here I’m really astonished with the performance test results. Thank you for bringing this issue up to me. My tests showed calculating the collatz sequence length [with no caching at all](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xpx3rSzV6thjfz1q) recursively or iteratively was faster than doing this [with cashing everything](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/34kZyVsTSknUjWiE) in an `unordered_map`!! Is `unordered_map` THAT slow, or am I doing things wrongly?

Comment: Regardless, I was trying to optimize lots of reads of different values rather than one huge read of `1-9999`. Not sure if I achieved my goal, though. I think I need to try caching just elts `1-9999` in an `std::array`.

Comment: Anyway, many thanks for Your answer, I really value it, like the answer above.

Comment: @gaazkam `std::unordered_map` isn't *that* slow, it is average O(1) search and insertion. Although maybe it is slow because you are storing every value in it? I have no idea though. (Don't use `std::array`, it would be even worse - compile time size and linear lookup)

Comment: Err if caching actually slows things down, then I guess something is wrong. Also [using `std::array` to cache first `999999` elts](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tT1ZIy9aUYAAROIF) managed to make the code run faster 5 times in comparison to [no caching at all](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xpx3rSzV6thjfz1q) and faster over 25 times in comparison to [caching everything in an `unordered_map`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/34kZyVsTSknUjWiE).

Comment: @gaazkam Ok, know I'm confused. Maybe the optimizer does some magic with `std::array`? Unlikely though.

Comment: As far as I know `std::array` can be viewed as a wrapper over a statically-allocated array (so we can view it as if it was sth like `int arr[999999]`, so it has O(1) lookup. `std::vector`, on the other hand, is (with a little oversimplification) a wrapper over a dynamically-allocated array, (so we can view it as if it was sth like `int *arr = new int[999999]`). So, `std::array`, just like a statically-allocated array, should be a little faster than `std::vector`, just like a dynamically-allocated array.

Comment: Lol. [Using `std::vector` to cache first `999999` elts](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tT1ZIy9aUYAAROIF) instead of `std::array` was faster over 2 times in comparison to [using `std::array` to cache first `999999` elts](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tT1ZIy9aUYAAROIF), faster almost 11 times in comparison to [no caching at all](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xpx3rSzV6thjfz1q) and faster over 59 times in comparison to [caching everything in `std::unordered_map`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/34kZyVsTSknUjWiE). Now I’m confused.

Comment: @gaazkam Well, you could always ask the question on SO :P I'm usre someone has an idea :)